# How to remove a row based on column conditions.?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I remove both record from the result, where `guest_id` are same and `fee_status` are different.

[image: dataset]

This is what I tried so far...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT g.guest_id,'Apr2020' as fee_month, 'Pending' as fee_status
    FROM .guest g
        LET JOIN managment.hostel_detail h
             ON g.h_id = h.h_id
    WHERE h.h_id = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  g.guest_id,f.fee_month,f.fee_status as fee_status
    FROM managment.guest g
        LEFT JOIN managment.fee f
            ON g.guest_id = f.guest_id
        LEFT JOIN managment.h_detail h
            ON g.h_id = h.h_id
    WHERE f.fee_status = 'Submitted'
        AND f.fee_month = 'Apr2020'
        AND h.h_id = 3
) main;
```

Comment: Make it easy and possible to assist you: [mcve]. (Start with showing us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text - not images.)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Screen shot has been added

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data as shown in the screenshot, you could use `aggregation` with a `having` clause to only select those rows that don't have an instance of duplicated fee_month and fee_status. If fee_month is not relevant, you can remove it from both `select` and `group by`.

```
select max(guest_id), fee_month, fee_status
from your_screenshot_table
group by fee_month, fee_status
having count(*)=1;
```